# Snap a point to a line and get the line ID (using the ArcGIS REST API)

Tags: proximity, snapping, arcgis-rest-api, arcgis-10.7, spatial-relationship

I have an external work order management system in which users create new sidewalk work orders (points).

When a user creates a sidewalk work order, a **J**ython script will invoke a URL that passes the X & Y coordinates of the work order to a map service/ArcGIS REST API (10.7.1).

In the map service/ArcGIS REST API, I want to process the X & Y coordinates as follows:

1. Find the **nearest** sidewalk to the X & Y coordinates (within a 5-metre distance) and get its ID.

   - Sidewalks are contained in a polyline EGDB feature class/feature service.
2. **Snap** the X & Y coordinates to the closest part of the sidewalk.
3. **Return** the sidewalk ID and the snapped coordinates to the work order management system.

Is it possible to do this using the ArcGIS REST API?

---

*Unfortunately, I only have the **Standard** ArcGIS Server license. So, while I **can** use a [geoprocessing service](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/what-is-a-geoprocessing-service-.htm), I cannot use the [Near](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/near.htm) tool.*

Comment: you can use custom geoprocessing with a model builder.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hint, hopefully someone can provide a more complete answer.

You could try with "[nearest Coordinate](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/latest/uwp/api-reference/html/M_Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Geometry_GeometryEngine_NearestCoordinate.htm)" from the GeometryEngine.

Alternatively, you could use a combination of "[FractionAlong](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/latest/uwp/api-reference/html/M_Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Geometry_GeometryEngine_FractionAlong.htm)" and "[create point along](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/latest/uwp/api-reference/html/M_Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Geometry_GeometryEngine_CreatePointAlong.htm)". The first will return the distance along a line for the point of the line that is clostest to your point. From this distance, you can use the second to create a point on the line.

Comment: This is runtime SDK for Xamarin Application development, not the enterprise server solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the custom arcpy toolbox for the solution.
[image]

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
in_featureclass = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
near_featureclass = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
out_featureclass = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)


arcpy.GenerateNearTable_analysis(in_featureclass, near_featureclass, out_featureclass, search_radius=5, location='LOCATION', closest=True)

output_layer=r'in_memory/layer'
arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(out_featureclass, 'NEAR_X', 'NEAR_Y', output_layer)

arcpy.SetParameterAsText(3, output_layer)
```

[image]